# Vue prop undefined in initial call to computed functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following Vue component:

```
Vue.component('result', {
  props: ['stuff'],
  data: () => ({}),
  template: "<img :src='tag' class='result'></img>",
  computed: {
    tag: function tag() {
      return `pages/search/img/${this.stuff.type.toLowerCase()}_tag.png`;
    }
  }
});
```

When the component is created, an error is thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
  at VueComponent.tag
```

However, when I remove the call to `toLowerCase()`, the method executes properly, generating a string with the expected type. I could work around this by changing my filenames to have capital letters, but I would rather understand why Vue is behaving this way. Why would a property be undefined only when methods are called on it?

**Update:** after some troubleshooting, I found that `this.stuff.type` is undefined the first time `tag()` is computed. Calling `toLowerCase()` just forces an error on an otherwise silent bug. Is there a reason the `props` aren't defined when `computed` functions are called for the first time? Should I be writing my component differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props are by default `null` but you can give them a default value to overcome this problem.

Example :

```
Vue.component('result', {
  props: {
    stuff: {
      type: Object,
      default: {
        type: ''
      }
    }
  },
  data: () => ({}),
  template: "<img :src='tag' class='result'></img>",
  computed: {
    tag: function tag() {
      return `pages/search/img/${this.stuff.type.toLowerCase()}_tag.png`;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The `stuff` prop is undefined when the `result` component is created.

There are two options to fix this problem:

Either use the `v-if` directive in the parent component's template to make sure `stuff` has a value when the `result` component is created:

```
<template>
  <result v-if="stuff" :stuff="stuff" />
</template>
```

Or handle the `stuff` prop being `undefined` in the `result` component.

```
Vue.component('result', {
  props: {
    // Object with a default value
    stuff: {
      type: Object,
      // Object or array defaults must be returned from
      // a factory function
      default: () => ({ type: 'someType'})
    },
  },

  data: () => ({}),

  template: "<img :src='tag' class='result' >",

  computed: {
    tag: function tag() {
      return `pages/search/img/${this.stuff.type.toLowerCase()}_tag.png`;
    }
  }
})
```

*Note: The `img` element is a void element, it does not require an end tag.*